# How can I move `wp_enqueue_scripts` to the Footer?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have placed the following code, into the `functions.php` file:

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/style.min.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

The above code, results in my Styles/Script loading within the Header.  How can I get the above code to load within the Footer instead?  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outputting styles outside the [`<head>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42608504/is-it-correct-to-use-the-style-tag-outside-of-the-head-element) tag is invalid HTML and it is a bad practice to do so.

However, WordPress still gives us the capability to enqueue styles in the footer by using the [print_late_styles()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/print_late_styles/) function. This prints the styles that were queued too late for the HTML head.

Comment: Strongly, strongly disagree with your opening sentence, but upvoted because this is the right way to get those styles in the footer.

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant to say, styles outside the <head> tag. Missed on that. 
Please share your concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would want your Styles and Scripts loaded within the Footer, rather than in the Header.  That said, simply place the following code, into your `functions.php` file:

```
remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' ); // Removes existing Styles/Scripts.

function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/style.min.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}

add_action( 'get_footer', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

If you are not the Theme Author, you should create a [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) first.  Otherwise your modifications will be lost, whenever a Theme update is processed.

Comment: Excellent.  Glad I could help.  I have also corrected your question, so that it says `functions.php` instead of `function.php`.  Just waiting for it to be peer reviewed. Good luck with your website! :-)

Comment: You want them loading in the footer in order to remove [render blocking CSS and scripts](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS)

Answer (score 1):

Outputting CSS in the footer is not exactly correct. However, in case of scripts, [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) has 5th argument, `$in_footer` which accepts `TRUE/FALSE` which will do exactly what you need it to do in case you pass `TRUE`.